# use php socket to keep receiving data

Tags: php

i need some clarifications in using a php socket.I explain now a little bit what i'm trying to do. I have a c++ application which collects data from the outside world (let's say inputs and outputs of an external device).I want to keep sending data to a webserver database through a socket.
The socket is already implemented in c++. The c++ application would acts as server, while the webserver as client. I thought about how to implement the webserver socket interface, and i decided to do it with a php script (i know a bit of this language,but i don't know if this is the best approach). I'm a newbie with php and all scripts i wrote so far were simple.

In this PHP script I would like something keep listening with a socket always connected. Is this possible in php ??

Thanks in advance
Paolo

Comment: Why PHP? Why not python? Have you looked at http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php ?

Comment: You can make the PHP-script run as a daemon (If on *nix-system, don't know about Windows), then it won't have to bother the webserver at all.

Comment: `$socket=socket_create (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP); socket_bind($socket,$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'],$port); socket_listen($socket);` Something like this?

Comment: IMHO whilst it can be done, PHP seems a poor fit for an always listening client. I would look to re-evaluate your architecture so your php is only called when needed rather than try to force php to be an always running always listening client

Comment: Yeah i heard about python, but i think i would be more confortable with php. Why do you advice me about it? Do you think it's better than php ?? Actually i'm running this on a linux environment, so the daemon way could be interesting.